# mapkit draw polyline with a dash pattern causes constant flickering on map

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

I've created various sets of polylines to be displayed on a mapkit map. When I set a lineDashPattern then view the map all the lines (whether solid or dashed) constantly flicker. Once I set the line style back to solid the issue goes away.
Thoughts to the issue or what I can test/check?
some snippets:

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
.......
NSMutableArray * lineDash = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [lineDash addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:20]];
.......
self setStrokeColor:[UIColor redColor]];
                         [self setLineWidth:2.0];
                         [self setLineDashPattern:lineDash];
.......
}
```

Currently I've found this 'flickering' to be due to an the drawMapRect running in an infinte loop when I set the LineDastPattern.

Answer (score 1):

Still not entirely sure why applying the styles to the path in MKOverlayPathView causes the issues, I'm thinking it was memory leaks somewhere. Nonetheeless, my solution is to apply the styles to the overlayView after the fact. 
e.g

```
MKOverlayPathView* overlayView = nil;
overlayView = [[[MKOverlayPathView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay] autorelease];
overlayView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
overlayView.lineWidth = 2.0;
overlayView.lineDashPattern =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:8], nil];
```